# Unit testing with ngStorage

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm assigning various values to local storage in our Jasmine unit tests like so:

```js
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $injector, $rootScope) {

$localStorage = $injector.get('$localStorage');
$localStorage.webAPIUrl = 'myUrl';

}

it('Can make API call', function() {

var apiCall = $localStorage.webAPIUrl + params;
httpBackend.expectGET(apiCall).respond({});

});
```

Unfortunately, anything I set in $localStorage is undefined when I try to retrieve it in the application, so tests like this fail because the angular service in the application utilizes $localStorage.webAPIUrl. These tests were fine previously (when we just stored values like this in window.AppConfig), but now we're running into this problem after switching to ngStorage.

Is there a piece of the puzzle I'm missing, or is there a problem with ngStorage and unit testing?

Comment: I'm expecting the same issue.. still digging..

Comment: Having the same problem. Investigating...